# PHP Oracle Connection DG?

Tags: php, oracle, performance, tcp

I wonder if you can provide me with sample code to make PHP connect to oracle data guard connection :

like the following:

```
(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(FAILOVER = ON)(LOAD_BALANCE = OFF)(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)(PORT = 1521))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXY)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = XDG)))
```

what I am using for now is one , but in order to achieve high availability

code so far is working on One connection string :

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '//XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/C1',
    'hostname' => $sq_hostname,
    'username' => $sq_dbusername,
    'password' => $sq_dbpassword,
    'database' => $sq_dbname,
    'dbdriver' => 'oci8',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE,
    'autoinit' => TRUE
);

$db['serverdb'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '//XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/C1',
    'hostname' => $sq_hostname,
    'username' => $sq_dbusername,
    'password' => $sq_dbpassword,
    'database' => $sq_dbname,
    'dbdriver' => 'oci8',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

adding the variables :

```
$tnsname ='(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = C1)))';

$sq_hostname=$tnsname;
$sq_dbname='C1';
$sq_dbusername='user';
$sq_dbpassword='password';
```

Comment: Ask a DBA, or perhaps ask on an Oracle forum.  The question is not PHP specific.

Comment: @ChristopherJones , what is needed from PHP is snippet of code to handle the connection string that was provided by the DBA ??

Comment: Do you mean like the PHP OCI8 manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php or in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html ?